# Calculate and plot time series of tasseled cap from Landsat8 in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, plot

My goal is to calculate TC for every image in the image collection and add it as another band to those images. (especially TCW and TCG). Then I would like to plot a scatter chart of the average TCW/TCG for my polygon over time. How can I achieve that?

I get error message metioning "Error in map(ID=LC08_192025_20130324):
Image.select: Pattern 'ST_B.*' did not match any bands."

I have a different script for computing TC for single image, but I am not able to map it over the entire collection somehow.

```
var calculateTasseledCap = function (image){
  var b = image.select("B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7");
  //Coefficients are only for Landsat 8 TOA
    var brightness_coefficents= ee.Image([0.3029, 0.2786, 0.4733, 0.5599, 0.508, 0.1872])
  var greenness_coefficents= ee.Image([-0.2941, -0.243, -0.5424, 0.7276, 0.0713, -0.1608]);
  var wetness_coefficents= ee.Image([0.1511, 0.1973, 0.3283, 0.3407, -0.7117, -0.4559]);
  var fourth_coefficents= ee.Image([-0.8239, 0.0849, 0.4396, -0.058, 0.2013, -0.2773]);
  var fifth_coefficents= ee.Image([-0.3294, 0.0557, 0.1056, 0.1855, -0.4349, 0.8085]);
  var sixth_coefficents= ee.Image([0.1079, -0.9023, 0.4119, 0.0575, -0.0259, 0.0252]);

    var brightness = image.expression(
            '(B * BRIGHTNESS)',
            {
                'B':b,
                'BRIGHTNESS': brightness_coefficents
                }
            );
  var greenness = image.expression(
    '(B * GREENNESS)',
            {
                'B':b,
                'GREENNESS': greenness_coefficents
                }
            );
  var wetness = image.expression(
    '(B * WETNESS)',
            {
                'B':b,
                'WETNESS': wetness_coefficents
                }
            );
  var fourth = image.expression(
      '(B * FOURTH)',
        {
          'B':b,
          'FOURTH': fourth_coefficents
          }
        );
  var fifth = image.expression(
      '(B * FIFTH)',
        {
          'B':b,
          'FIFTH': fifth_coefficents
          }
        );
  var sixth = image.expression(
    '(B * SIXTH)',
    {
      'B':b,
      'SIXTH': sixth_coefficents
      }
    );
  brightness = brightness.reduce(ee.call("Reducer.sum"));
  greenness = greenness.reduce(ee.call("Reducer.sum"));
  wetness = wetness.reduce(ee.call("Reducer.sum"));
  fourth = fourth.reduce(ee.call("Reducer.sum"));
  fifth = fifth.reduce(ee.call("Reducer.sum"));
  sixth = sixth.reduce(ee.call("Reducer.sum"));
  var tasseled_cap = ee.Image(brightness).addBands(greenness).addBands(wetness)
                             .addBands(fourth)
                             .addBands(fifth)
                             .addBands(sixth).rename('brightness','greenness','wetness','fourth','fifth','sixth')
  return tasseled_cap;
};

function maskScaleAndAddVariable(image) {
    // Bit 0 - Fill
    // Bit 1 - Dilated Cloud
    // Bit 2 - Cirrus
    // Bit 3 - Cloud
    // Bit 4 - Cloud Shadow
    var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111',
        2)).eq(0);
    var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

    // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
    var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-
        0.2);
    var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802)
        .add(149.0);

    // Replace the original bands with the scaled ones and apply the masks.
    var img = image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
        .addBands(thermalBands, null, true)
        .updateMask(qaMask)
        .updateMask(saturationMask);
    var imgScaled = image.addBands(img, null, true);

    // Now we start to add variables of interest.
    // Compute time in fractional years since the epoch.
    var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
    var years = date.difference(ee.Date('1970-01-01'), 'year'); //Unix time[a] is the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970, excluding leap seconds. 
    // Return the image with the added bands.
    return imgScaled
        // Add an NDVI band.
        .addBands(imgScaled.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4'])
            .rename('NDVI'))
         .addBands(imgScaled.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B6'])
            .rename('NDMI'))
        // Add a time band.
        .addBands(ee.Image(years).rename('t'))
        .float()
        // Add a constant band.
        .addBands(ee.Image.constant(1));
}

var lsib = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
var country = lsib.filterMetadata('country_na','equals','Czechia');
Map.centerObject(country,8);

//---------------------- DATE-------------------------//
var startDate = ee.Date('2013-01-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2022-01-01')

//---------------------- DATASETS-------------------------//
var landsat_8_sr = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")
  .filterBounds(country)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .map(maskScaleAndAddVariable);
  
print("All L8 images in defined interval: ", landsat_8_sr.size());

var landsat8ChartTL = ui.Chart.image.series(landsat_8_sr.select('NDVI'), table)
    .setChartType('ScatterChart')
    .setOptions({
        title: 'Landsat 8 NDVI time series at ROI',
        trendlines: {
            0: {
                color: 'CC0000'
            }
        },
        lineWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 3,
    });
    
var landsat8_tasseled_cap = landsat_8_sr.map(calculateTasseledCap);

// reduce tasseled cap collection to an image so we can use .reduceRegion()
var tasseledcapImg = landsat8_tasseled_cap.mosaic()

var reducer = ee.Reducer.mean() // change to whichever reducer you would like to use

// map over each feature in the city collection
var city_stats = table.map(function(feature){
  // reduce the feature to get band statistics
  var zonalStats = tasseledcapImg.reduceRegion({
    reducer: reducer,
    geometry:feature.geometry(),
    scale:30
  })
  // return same feature but with the zonal stat results
  return feature.set(zonalStats)
})
```